# Creating Semantic Slice from C# Program using AST and PDG

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-syntax-tree, ilspy, dnspy

I'm experimenting with creating a semantic slice from a C# program and have obtained the abstract syntax tree (AST) and program dependence graph (PDG). However, I'm unsure where to start  generate a semantic slice.

I am looking for a guide or suggestions on the general process to accomplish this task. I don't have specific source code to share right now as I need general guidance first.

Does anyone have ideas, tutorials, or suggestions on the overall workflow for this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you, everyone!